# search a pattern and update the record with the first occurrence of that pattern

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

I have a file that contains records with an identifier. For each identifier, there may be multiple records. I want to search all records with the same identifier and look for a particular pattern (Y at specific position) in those records; if the pattern exists, I want to update the first record for that indicator with that pattern.  How can I best accomplish that with scripting? (Unix or windows). The file is already sorted by identifier.
Here is a sample of what I want to accomplish:

```
identifier1aaaNbbb  
identifier1cccNddd  
identifier1eeeYfff
```

if, one of the records for identifier1 has a 'Y' at position 14, then write that 'Y' to the first occurrence of the identifier1 record, i.e.,

```
identifier1aaaYbbb  
identifier1cccNddd  
identifier1eeeYfff
```

I am not sure what tool (`awk`, `grep`, `sed`) would be best suited for this? Any idea how to tackle it?

Comment: Are all the records the same length? Are there records other than `identifier1`?

Comment: all records are the same length. There will be many different identifiers in the file and for each identifier, there may be multiple records.

Comment: Is each identifier 11 characters long? Or how do we know where an identifier ends?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and reading the input file twice to process it.

This is under the assumption that your identifier is 11 characters long and that you're looking for lines with `Y` as the 15th character (as in your example). If the identifier is not always 11 characters long, then the first line of the script needs to be modified.

First pass: Save the first record for each identifier in an array and modify this array element if a record with `Y` is found.

Second pass: Replace the line of the first record for each identifier with the saved and possibly modified array value and print the line.

```
awk '{
  ident=substr($0,0,11)  # get identifier
  if (NR==FNR){          # first pass
    if (!(ident in a)){  # if identifier is not present in array
      a[ident]=$0        # save current line in array
    }
    if (substr($0,15,1) == "Y"){  # if `Y` is found in current line
                                  # replace character with `Y` in array value
      a[ident]=substr(a[ident],0,14)"Y"substr(a[ident],16)
    }
  }
  else {               # second pass
    if (ident in a){   # if identifier is present in array
      $0=a[ident]      # replace current line
      delete a[ident]  # delete array element
    }
    print              # print current line
  }
}' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOT** elegant. For informational purposes only.

First, identify all of the `identifier1` records
command1: `grep '^identifier1' my_file_name`
This will print *only* the lines with your chosen tag. Later, you can look for records with a different identifier.

Once you have these records, you can search *just* column 14, with the cut command:
command2: `_command1_ | cut -c14`
For clarity, I'm using shorthand notation on the commands. Hope they makes sense to you.
command2 uses the cut command to only print the 14th character (`-c` for Character).

You can then look for 'Y' in this output.
command3: `_command2_ | grep -q Y`  The -q says "Quiet" -- don't output anything.
`rc=$?`   Note: Some say you don't need rc, just look at $?. Your call.
At this point, if $rc (or $?) is 0, grep found at least one upper case Y. Otherwise, it will be 1 (other numbers are possible, indicating an error).

Let's code that this way:
`if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "No Ys found"
  exit
fi`
Note: if you place ANY commands between the `grep -q Y` and the `if`, you MUST use the `rc=$?` Otherwise $? is fine.

To change ALL of the indicators for N to Y, you would run this sed command:

```
sed -i "/^identifier1/ s/\(………….\).\(.*\)/\1Y\2/" my_file_name
```

The `-i` says In-place editing of the file.
the `/^identifier1/` says only match lines starting with *indetifier1*
the `s` means search and replace. The SearchFor is after the / The Replace With is after the next slash.
SearchFor: You want the 14th character. There is an elegant way to do this in *sed*. I'll leave that for other folks to explain. The simple answer is:
-dot- means any character. So 13 dots means match the first 13 characters. Because we want to keep these in-tact, we'll store them in a bucket. The is it ( and ) -- escaped parenthesis. So:
`/\( 13 dots \) . \( dot * \)` say grab the first 13 characters of the line and store them in Bucket #1. the dot means match 1 character. the dot star says "Match 0 or more characters" -- i.e. everything else -- and store it in Bucket #2.

Now for the replace:
`/\1Y\2/` says Replace the line with the contents of Bucket #1, followed by Y and then Bucket #2.

There is a way to clean this up and make it more efficient. I don't a Linux box in front of me and can't remember off the top of my head how to do it.
When some other **FAB** folks post it up, you ought to be able to understand it now.